# Wordpress: Widget in header flows behing logo in mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, header, widget

I am almost done with a site I am working on in Wordpress - I am just having one major issue...

I figured out how to add a widget to the header of the TwentyEleven theme - and it works great, except when viewed in mobile or the window in shrunk down - the widget will display behind the logo. I would like for the widget to display below the logo in mobile view.

Here is the site: http://www.lawncarelancasterpa.com

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You `#arphabet` element is absolute positioned

Answer (score 0):

#branding #arphabet

line no 26 in style.css position is absolute. Remove position property.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:inline-block;` to your `<hgroup>` and then remove the absolute position from `#arphabet` and also add `display:inline-block;`

Add padding or margin to adjust position as needed.

Add this to your CSS:

```
#branding hgroup{ display:inline-block; }
#branding #arphabet {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```